# What's wrong with my def function? how to fix it?

Tags: python, string, list, function

The data is:
[('1985-08', '15.00'), ('1985-08', '14.88'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.13'), ('1985-08', '14.75'), ('1985-08', '14.88'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.00'), ('1985-08', '14.63'), ('1985-08', '14.50'), ('1985-08', '14.63'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.00'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.13'), ('1985-08', '14.88'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.38'), ('1985-08', '15.75'), ('1985-08', '15.88'), ('1985-07', '15.88'), ('1985-07', '16.25'), ('1985-07', '16.00'), ('1985-07', '16.62'), ('1985-07', '16.62'), ('1985-07', '16.25'), ('1985-07', '16.50'), ('1985-07', '16.87'), ('1985-07', '17.37'), ('1985-07', '17.25'), ('1985-07', '17.62'), ('1985-07', '17.50'), ('1985-07', '17.75'), ('1985-07', '17.87'), ('1985-07', '18.00'), ('1985-07', '18.00'), ('1985-07', '17.62'), ('1985-07', '17.62'), ('1985-07', '17.62'), ('1985-07', '17.50'), ('1985-07', '17.25'), ('1985-07', '18.12')]

My code:

```
def average_data(list_of_tuples):
strMonth = []
counter = 0
addition = 0
while True:
    if (strMonth[counter])[0] == (strMonth[counter+1])[0]:    #line 31
        addition += float(strMonth[counter][1])
        result2 = addition
    else:
        continue
print(result2)
return result2
def main(): 
    file_obj = get_input_descriptor()
    column = int(input('What column:'))
    get_data_list(file_obj, column)
    result2 =get_data_list(file_obj, column)

average_data(result2)
file_obj.close()
main()
```

The Python Shell's Error code:

```
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\proj.py", line 31, in average_data
if (strMonth[counter])[0] == (strMonth[counter+1])[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What wrong with it? I want to get the sum of number of each month. Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: you should explain what your trying to do, it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strMonth` is empty. It has no 0-th element, so `strMonth[counter]` raises an `IndexError`:

```
In [29]: strMonth = []

In [30]: counter = 0

In [31]: strMonth[counter]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

You could use a `dict` (or a [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) to map yearmonth strings to a float representing the sum of the values.

```
import collections
def average_data(strMonth):
    result = collections.defaultdict(float)
    for yearmonth, val in strMonth:
        result[yearmonth] += float(val)
    return dict(result)

def main(): 
    result2 = [('1985-08', '15.00'), ('1985-08', '14.88'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.13'), ('1985-08', '14.75'), ('1985-08', '14.88'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.00'), ('1985-08', '14.63'), ('1985-08', '14.50'), ('1985-08', '14.63'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.00'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.13'), ('1985-08', '14.88'), ('1985-08', '15.25'), ('1985-08', '15.38'), ('1985-08', '15.75'), ('1985-08', '15.88'), ('1985-07', '15.88'), ('1985-07', '16.25'), ('1985-07', '16.00'), ('1985-07', '16.62'), ('1985-07', '16.62'), ('1985-07', '16.25'), ('1985-07', '16.50'), ('1985-07', '16.87'), ('1985-07', '17.37'), ('1985-07', '17.25'), ('1985-07', '17.62'), ('1985-07', '17.50'), ('1985-07', '17.75'), ('1985-07', '17.87'), ('1985-07', '18.00'), ('1985-07', '18.00'), ('1985-07', '17.62'), ('1985-07', '17.62'), ('1985-07', '17.62'), ('1985-07', '17.50'), ('1985-07', '17.25'), ('1985-07', '18.12')]
    print(average_data(result2))
main()
```

yields

```
{'1985-07': 378.08000000000004, '1985-08': 332.16999999999996}
```

Answer (score 0):

python 3.2

```
  M=List_of_tuples

  sum(int(m.split("-")[1]) for m,t in M)
```